# Ordering NSDate Array. Swift 2

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nsdate

I have 1 date array and 1 2D array which holds values.

e.g:

```
func orderArrays() {
    var dateArray : [NSDate] = []
    var values : [[Double]] = [[]]
    dateArray = [01-01-2016, 02-01-16, 08-01-16, 03-01-2016]
    values = [[2.0, 4.6, 5.6, 3.8], [7.2, 6.4, 1.6, 7.2]]
 }
```

`values[0][0]` &`values[1][0]` represent values for `dateArray[0]`.

I need to order `dateArray` (earliest first), which also re-orders the values accordingly.

for example, the final arrays would look like:

```
dateArray = [01-01-2016, 02-01-16, 03-01-2016, 08-01-16]
values = [[2.0, 4.6, 3.8, 5.6], [7.2, 6.4, 7.2, 1.6]]
```

`dateArray[3]` is now `dateArray[2]` which leads onto `values[0][3]` now being `values[0][2]` & `values[1][3]` now being `values[1][2]`

It is required for the final arrays to look like so as i am using this data to create charts. I will always have 2 arrays however the inner array within value can be infinite (not always 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below to get the required answer.

I created a sorted array, and created an array holding the index of the original dates in the sorted format. This was then used to sort the value array using the same index order.

```
 let sortedArray = dateArray.sort { $0.compare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }

    var indexOfDates : [Int] = []

    for i in sortedArray {
        let index = dateArray.indexOf(i)
        indexOfDates.append(index!)
    }
    var sortedTotalSpent : [[Double]] = [[0.0]]
    var sortedSpend : [Double] = [0.0]
    sortedTotalSpent.removeAll()
    sortedSpend.removeAll()

    for i in value {
        for x in indexOfDates {
            print("i = \(i)")
            print("x = \(x)")
            print("i[x] = \(i[x])")
            sortedSpend.append(i[x])
        }
        sortedTotalSpent.append(sortedSpend)
        sortedSpend.removeAll()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative1: Change your data structure**

Your structure could be enhanced. For example, you could save your data like this (I also have let the dates as Strings, usually you would have to convert them to NSDate with a NSDateFormatter):

```
var dateValueArray: [(date: NSDate, values: [Double])]
dateValueArray = [(date: "01-01-2016", values: [2.0, 7.2]),
                  (date: "02-01-2016", values: [4.6, 6.4]),
                  (date: "08-01-2016", values: [5.6, 3.8]),
                  (date: "03-01-2016", values: [3.8, 7.2])]
```

that structure could be sorted this way:

```
let sortedArray = dateValueArray.sort { $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

**Alternative2: Sort your structure**

Your initial structure could be sorted like this:

1: Sort the data

```
let sortedArray = Zip2Sequence(dateArray, Zip2Sequence(values[0], values[1])).sort({ $0.0.compare($1.0) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
```

2: Convert the resulting data structure (`(date, (value0, value1))`) back to the initial one and assign it to the arrays:

```
dateArray = sortedArray.reduce([], combine: {$0 + [$1.0]})
let values0 = sortedArray.reduce([], combine: {$0 + [$1.1.0]})
let values1 = sortedArray.reduce([], combine: {$0 + [$1.1.1]})
values = [values0, values1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was looking to do it that way as I will use the arrays for a graph. Alternative2 is exactly what i am looking for however I am retrieving the values from core data and there isn't always 2 values. How can i manipulate this to account for an unknown number of values?

Comment: @JessMurray instead of `Zip2Sequence(values[0], values[1])` create the values array with a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

it sort an array with NSDate data. If you remember previous position of element in array you can get new position a just change it. I did something like this but I replaced arrays with Dictionary in your case I would use:

`var dictionary = [NSDate : Array<Array<CGFloat>>]()`

```
        var dateArray : [NSDate] = []
        var values : [[Double]] = [[]]

        let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        //creating the dates
        for i in 1 ..< 10{
            let date = dateformatter.dateFromString("01-0\(10-i)-2016")
            dateArray.append(date!)
        }
        let sortedArray = dateArray.sort({$0.compare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
```